# Update with limit or something like that

Tags: mysql, sql

Query:

```
update cities c
inner join regions r on (c.region = r.region_id and c.code = r.country_code)
set c.region_id = r.id;
```

There are 3 million records in cities so MySQL server fails during execution.

Is there a way to use it with limit? For each 100 thousands of records?

Or any other way to perform that query?

Cities table schema

```
CREATE TABLE `cities` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `native_city` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `region` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `population` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lat` decimal(9,7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lon` decimal(9,7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `region_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3173959 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

`country_id`, `region_id` not foreign keys. just empty fields, that I want to fill with values from another tables and then I'll add `fk`.

Comment: 3 million? Properly indexed, MySQL wouldn't even break a sweat.

Comment: What does the schema of the tables look like?

Comment: If `c.region_id` is currently `null` (looks like you're migrating?) you could simply add a `LIMIT` clause and a `WHERE c.region_id IS NULL` but as it is I can't figure out exactly what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Have you tried doing this from the command line using SSH or whatever?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [MySQL UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

> For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE updates rows in each table named
>   in table_references that satisfy the conditions. Each matching row is
>   updated once, even if it matches the conditions multiple times. For
>   multiple-table syntax, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.

But you can hide ORDER BY and LIMIT into a subquery and then JOIN it with original table to update. Here is an example:

```
update cities c
inner join 
   (select c1.id,r.id as r_id from cities c1
      inner join regions r on (c1.region = r.region_id 
                               and c1.code = r.country_code)
      order by c1.id
      LIMIT 1000
   ) c2 on   c.id=c2.id 
set c.region_id = c2.r_id
```